Как помочь словарям пополнить их словарный запас?
Я считаю, что большие и известные словари не поспевают за наплывом новых слов и нагло деградируют на глазах общественности. Как любящий русский язык человек,я хочу им помочь либо со словарями неологизмов, либо с большими онлайн словарями. Какие из них принимают помощь сообщества?

например, каких слов?

В зависимости от того, какие слова в словарях отсутствуют. С учётом того, что в словаре Российской академии наук только в прошлом году добавили слово "суши", такой вопрос не стоит и близко.

Словарь академии наук, может быть, не для всех прямо названий блюд, может быть там, ну, важные слова какие-то?  А для изделий из рыбы есть и другие словари - Кулинарный словарь?

А словарь ран - это узкоспециализированный словарь? Вроде нет. Раз включили "суши", полагаю, "сурими" тоже можно добавить. А его нет. Я бы проверил, есть ли оно у Ефремовой, да у них проблемы со словами - ерунда по сравнению с проблемой работоспособности официального сайта. Надеюсь, я смог донести суть дела.

Ну можно им написать, попросить добавить. Если честно, я не знаю, что такое сурими и зачем заполнять словари транслитерированной калькой иностранных слов.

https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/сурими

すりみ【擂り身】(сурими)
отбитое и мелко изрубленное мясо; отбитая и мелко изрубленная рыба. - то есть рыбный фарш.
Фарш - вас не устраивает? Или - рубленное мясо рыбы? Смысл помещать слово, которое ничего не значит в словарь?

擂 - рубить, колотить.

Тогда немедленно забываем слово "прощай". У нас есть слово "пока". Забываем "привет", у нас есть "здравствуй". "Мобила", "труба", "смартфон", "трубка", "сотик", "мобильник". Зачем? Ведь у нас есть слово "телефон'! Зачем вы используете слово "смысл", когда есть слово "цель"?  Немедленно забудем 200 000 + слов! Зачем они нам, когда средний человек, дай бог, хотя бы 12 000 использует. Буратино, а вам точно интересен и важен русский язык?

Или вы предлагаете запретить это слово к использованию? Ценники, производства, повара должны, по вашему, немедленно отказаться от этого слова? Возможно, вы считаете, что этот неологизм вымрет через год, два? Что ж, кажется мне, он с нами надолго. Придётся смириться и записать его в словарь. Как и многие иные слова в том числе. Иначе получится, как слово "чепок". Никто не знает, как оно пишется, какова его этимология, сокращение это или нет. Потому что не обратили на него внимание в нужный момент. Надо ли говорить, что таких слов сотни? Upd: Чепок, чапок, чипок, чпок - магазины при армиях.

Я предлагаю писать на ценниках : すりみСУРИМИ(рыбный фарш). И почему, то что слово отсутвует в словаре, его нельзя произносить. Просто "сурими" - это просто звукоподражание слову, которое можно перевести на русский, без особой потери смысла.

"Мобила", "труба", "смартфон", "трубка", "сотик", "мобильник". - в словаре РАН есть? Все за исключением смартфона, который калька с инглиша, это сленг, а не слова языка. Чипок - тоже сленг, кстати говоря, потому что: Явно шуточный характер носит и расшифровка слова "Чипок" как "чрезвычайная индивидуальная помощь оголодавшим курсантам (контрактникам). Какая разница, как пишется сленг?

Зачем они нам, когда средний человек, дай бог, хотя бы 12 000 использует. Буратино, а вам точно интересен и важен русский язык? - неправда, в русском языке очень много слов, просто принцип словообразования иной, корней меньше, а слов даже больше, чем в инглише и других языках. И даже самый необразованный человек знает таких слов не мало, а если не знает, то может самостоятельно составить слово.

А насчет звукоподражанию словам японского и китайского языка - в этом нет почти никакого смысла, если это не суперпопулярное слово. Потому что у них, опять же, иной принцип словообразования, отличный от русского и от отлатинских языков.

Спасибо за дискуссию. Боюсь, слишком пуста, чтоб продолжать. Оставлю вам строчки из Евгения Онегина.     В последнем вкусе туалетом
Заняв ваш любопытный взгляд,
Я мог бы пред ученым светом
Здесь описать его наряд;
Конечно б это было смело,
Описывать мое же дело:
Но панталоны, фрак, жилет,
Всех этих слов на русском нет;
А вижу я, винюсь пред вами,
Что уж и так мой бедный слог
Пестреть гораздо б меньше мог
Иноплеменными словами,
Хоть и заглядывал я встарь
В Академический словарь.

Ну вот, как всегда - опять об Пушкина!)
